Grafana datapoints date
I'm just wondering if it is possible to display the first and last datapoint of a query in a table series.
As I wanted to perform an audit on my queries and alerts to pick the right threshold

As you can see in this picture, I wanted to get the first data point (first arrow) and last datapoint (2nd arrow) to get the dates in a table series.
Or probably like what is the time difference between first and last datapoint if possible
I tried to explore other functions and panels but i have no idea which one to select.

I don't think panel with functionality you describe exists (at least vanilla one).

In some very limited capacity you probably can try to use queries like (<query> unless <query> offset 15s) or (<query> unless <query> offset -15s), where <query> is your initial query, to get starting and ending points. And then substract them with Transformations. But it'll be very finicky and very limited.
